# Access 'this' inside a function on drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have the following code for a drag event:

```
BusinessProductFigure.prototype = new Figure();
BusinessProductFigure.prototype.constructor = BusinessProductFigure;
BusinessProductFigure.prototype.addTo = function(c, x0, y0, id) {
console.log("this=",this);
var n = d3.select(this);
var wasMoved = false;
var dragger = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d){return d;})
    .on("drag", this.move)
    .on("dragend", dropHandler)
```

The function **this.move** executes in the above code and performs it's designated function. However, I want to add a function that is called upon on drag event. I tried the following:

```
BusinessProductFigure.prototype.addTo = function(c, x0, y0, id) {
console.log("this=",this);
var n = d3.select(this);
var wasMoved = false;
var dragger = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d){return d;})
    .on("drag", function(){wasMoved=true; this.move})
    .on("dragend", dropHandler)
```

But the above code does not calls the move function. How can I access 'this' property inside the function?

Comment: I dont understand the reason to down vote the question. If someone is a beginner and is unable to figure out some code, is it wrong to ask? Isn't the community here to support developers and help new coders learn and improve?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind relevant context using `bind()`, and use parenthensis to call the method:

`.on("drag", function(){wasMoved=true; this.move()}.bind(this))`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution because it's 2016 already is to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve lexical context:

```
.on("drag", () => {
   wasMoved = true;
   this.move()
})
```